# Packages unauthorized when installing visual studio code on raspberry pi 3

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi3

When trying to install visual studio code on my raspberry pi 3, it would say

The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  code-oss
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated

I've tried to install it by using root but the same message popped up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812146/unauthenticated-packages) , you'll see that you can either:

- do what the output says, i.e. adding the `--allow-authenticated` option to the command line when installing
- or, validate the key downloading the key itself from https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/gpgkey and then using: `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys [key]`, where `[key]` is the file that you downloaded.

Anyway this should not be necessary if you use the command specified on the website, which should include the check in the install script: `. <( wget -O - https://code.headmelted.com/installers/apt.sh )`

(And BTW, if you look at the script code, you'll see that there is a commented out line with exactly the `--allow-authenticated' option )